# Multiselect with React MUI/Material does not show the selected options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing a dynamic form with React. At this point I have 2 components apparently related with my problem, the `<FullTrainingForm/>` and the `<DynamicForm>`. The first one includes a state where I store the values from my form, and other one that I use to print the form. The  iterate the states defined in the `<FullTrainingForm/>` and print a normal input, or a multiselect, but in the future I would like to have more cases and print the form defining the inputs in the DB.

The problem I have is that my multiselect does not show the values salected despite I have checked that the values are being correctly stored in the state (in step1Data, property injuries: []). I am not having any error so it's really difficult to identify what is wrong.

I will share all the code that I consider it's important to read.

Code Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-resonance-u9eg3?file=/src/components/FullTrainingForm.js
There is a console.log which shows the array, and you will see that is has the correct value, but the select always appears empty.

FullTrainingForm.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { pink, yellow, blue, grey } from '@mui/material/colors';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import FitnessCenterIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FitnessCenter';


import DynamicForm from './form/DynamicForm';
import ButtonAddExercise from './form/buttons/ButtonAddExercise';
import ButtonNextStep from './form/buttons/ButtonNextStep';

import MultipleSelectCheckmarks from './form/Multiple';

function FullTrainingForm() {

    // ******* 
    //  Step 1 
    // *******

     // Data to save
     const [step1Data, setStep1Data] = useState({
        description: '',
        effort: '',
        feeling: '',
        injuries: [],
        date_training: ''
    })
    
    // Input event
    const handleInputsChange1 = (num, event) => {
        if(event.target.name == 'injuries') {
            setStep1Data({
                ...step1Data,
                [event.target.name]: [...step1Data.injuries, event.target.value[0]] // I push the value selected in the Multiselect to the injuries[] property from the step1Data.
            });
        }
        else {
            setStep1Data({
                ...step1Data,
                [event.target.name] : event.target.value
            })
        }
        console.log(step1Data.injuries)
    }


    // Form 
    const [step1Inputs, setStep1Inputs] = useState([
       {id: uuid(), tag: '', name: 'description', type: '', label: 'Describe your training', icon: 'description', icon_color: blue[500]},
       {id: uuid(), tag: '', name: 'effort', type: '', label: 'Rate your effort (1 - 10)', icon: 'bolt', icon_color: yellow[800]},
       {id: uuid(), tag: '', name: 'feeling', type: '', label: 'How do you feel (1 - 10)', icon: 'favoriteborder', icon_color: pink[500]},
       {id: uuid(), tag: 'multi-select', name: 'injuries', data_array: step1Data, type: '', label: 'Injuries or pain? Select a muscle', icon: 'favoriteborder', icon_color: grey[900]},
       {id: uuid(), tag: '', name: 'date_training', type: 'date', label: '', icon: '', icon_color: ''}
    ])

    // Submit Event

    const handleSubmitStep1 = () => {
        // console.log(training)
        axios.post('/trainingsessions/test', step1Data)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            setRenderStep2(true)
            setCountExercises(countExercises+1)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("ERROR:: ",error.response.data)
        });
    }

 return (
        <Box  
            sx={{ mx: "auto", mt: 5, mb: 5, width: "50%" }} 
        >
            <Grid container>
                {/* Step 1 */}
                <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
                    <DynamicForm 
                        title = 'New Training' 
                        show = {true}
                        input_list = {step1Inputs} 
                        data_form = {step1Data} 
                        event_input = {handleInputsChange1}
                    />

                    <ButtonNextStep 
                        show = { true }
                        text = 'Next step'
                        event_input={handleSubmitStep1}
                    />
                </Grid>
           </Grid>
        </Box>
    )

}

export default FullTrainingForm;

if (document.getElementById('TrainingSeassonForm_id')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<FullTrainingForm />, document.getElementById('TrainingSeassonForm_id'));
}
```

DynamicForm.js

```
import React, {useState}  from 'react';

import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';

import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import InputAdornment from '@mui/material/InputAdornment';
import Icon from '@mui/material/Icon';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import OutlinedInput from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';


import { muscles } from '../../other_data/muscles';


const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

const mydate = new Date();
const dateok = mydate.getFullYear() + '-' + (mydate.getMonth() + 1)  + '-' + mydate.getDate();
console.log(dateok)
const values = {
    date: dateok
};


// Import list of muscles from a file
const muscle_list = muscles




function DynamicForm(props) {


    const renderTitle = <Typography variant="h3" align="left" key={uuid()}>{props.title}</Typography>
    
    const renderInputs = props.input_list.map((input) => {
        let id_label_select = "demo-multiple-name-label-"+input.name
        if(input.tag == 'multi-select')
            if(input.name == 'injuries' || input.name.includes('injuriesex')) // Special case
                return ( 
                    <div>
                    <FormControl sx={{ width: '100%', mt: 1 }}>
                        <InputLabel id={id_label_select}>{input.label}</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            sx={{ width: '100%'}}
                            key={input.id}
                            name={input.name}
                            labelId={id_label_select}
                            multiple
                            value={input.data_array.injuries}
                            inputProps={{
                                'data-num': input.num
                            }}
                            onChange={(e)=>props.event_input(input.num, e)}
                            input={
                                <OutlinedInput label={input.label} />
                            }
                            
                            MenuProps={MenuProps} 
                        >
                            {muscles.map((name, index) => (
                            <MenuItem
                                key={index}
                                value={name}
                            >
                                {name}
                            </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                        </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                    </div>
            )
            else
                return null; // TO DO
      else if (input.type == 'subtitle')
        return (
            <div>
                {input.icon}
                <Typography sx={{ mt:2, ml: 2, color: '#6d9dd3', display: 'inline-block'}} variant="h5" align="left" key={uuid()}>{input.label}</Typography>
            </div>
        ) 
      else
      return (
          <div>
            <TextField 
            
            key={input.id}
            name={input.name} 
            type={input.type}
            onChange={(e)=>props.event_input(input.num, e)} 
            label={input.label} 
            inputProps={{
                'data-num': input.num
            }}
            variant="outlined" 
            fullWidth  
            margin='dense' 
            InputProps={{ 
                endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position='start'>
                        <Icon sx={{ color: input.icon_color }}>{input.icon}</Icon>
                    </InputAdornment>
                )
            }} 
            /> 
        </div>
      )
    }

    );
   

    if(props.show) {
        return (
            <div>
                {renderTitle}
                {renderInputs}
            </div>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (
            null
        )
    }
}

export default DynamicForm;
```

Thank you,

Comment: Can you provide a [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: @hotcakedev Hi, this is the link: Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-resonance-u9eg3?file=/src/components/FullTrainingForm.js. If you read the console you will see that the the selected values are pushed into the array  but you will not see anything in the multiselect

Comment: Just looked through the codesandbox. It doesn't set any value actually. The `data_array.injuries` is always length 0 and after onChange event has happened, the `input` array changes and remove the injuries value eventually. You should try more and keep me posted your updates.

Comment: @hotcakedev , finally it works. I had two ways to access the step1Data.injuries array: 
1) (Does not works). Parent pass the data as a prop.input.step1Data.injuries (this is when I iterate the inputs with the map in the chld element, and when I selected a new value, the component was restarted.
2) Solution: To pass the state as a general prop, like prop.step1Data.injuries. In this case it works.
Honestly, I do not know why... You can check the code again and you will see how it works.

Comment: @hotcakedev My explanation is, my child receives the step1Data and the step1Inputs,  both of them are states. I was passing the step1Data to the step1Inputs, and the child was accessing to the step1Data through the step1Inputs, and I guess that, when the component changes, the component is restarted and it loses the info. Anyway, is a bad idea to access one state trought othe state because the solution was to access the state directly. I hope I was clear with my "theory".